# Move image to the center

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move the image right before the text inside the same `div`. For `div` I give CSS `text-align:center`, but it only affects on the text. How to move the image right before the text?

http://jsfiddle.net/j5nwS/1/

Comment: Every thing is fine , just add  margin-left:80px; to css (ui-icon)

Comment: No, if the text is longer, that won't work

Comment: Not tried.Let me try.

Comment: Yes, It will work but you have to set the first div height (min-height:30px) .But , no need . If you donot have the data then why these symbols required.So, if you have dynamic data, then you can check that data is available or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `span`' `display` property to `inline-block`.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j5nwS/14/

Answer (score 0):

Add the below css to the **ui-icon** class:

**EDIT:**

```
.ui-icon {        
    display: inline-block;  
    position: relative;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/j5nwS/18/)

Comment: then it is above of the text. I need it on the left side, before the text

Comment: Instead of block, use `inline-block;` check this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j5nwS/18/

Answer (score 0):

If you add this:

```
    .ui-icon-carat-1-s{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    }
```

this will work. http://jsfiddle.net/j5nwS/6/

Answer (score 0):

Remove "overflow: hidden; position: absolute; " and change "display" to "inline-block":

```
.ui-icon {
  background-image: url("https://raw.github.com/gallery/gallery3-vendor/9a462c4c81c755cc4ff84c856d4c0f6ea47b9cd8/ui.themeroller/modified/images/ui-icons_217bc0_256x240.png");
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;  
  display: inline-block;
}
```